# Swift override method didPressSend

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0 and JSQMessages 7.3.4.

I am trying to implement JSQMessagesViewController and specifically, I am trying to override the didPressSend function yet it keep complaining that the method does not override any method from its superclass.

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton, withMessageText text: String, senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String, date: Date) {
    print("working")
}
```

Any thoughts on why this might be?

It also complains method cannot be an @obj override because type of parameter 5 cannot be represented in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton?, withMessageText text: String?, senderId: String?, senderDisplayName: String?, date: Date?) {
    // Check to make sure we are sending something no need for blank messages.
    guard let text = text else {
        return
    }
    print("working")
    // add logic here.
}
```

practice safe code out there.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this worked although I had to delete the conversation.smsNumber - what is that?

Comment: That is just my variable. My bad :)

Comment: I use that for posting my message to the backend. So where I added the add logic here comment I have a method that posts to the back end and adds the message to my list of messages locally.

Comment: So its just a conversation object that I have created that has a smsNumber property. That way I can display a list of conversations and once selected the whole chat"Conversation" and all its messages are displayed.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the errors by typing `override func didpress` and then accepting the suggested completion. There you will see that there are some subtle differences, most notable the force-unwrapped optionals:

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, 
               withMessageText text: String!, 
                           senderId: String!, 
                  senderDisplayName: String!, 
                               date: Date!) {
    print("works")
}
```

Comment: Hi Mundi, I did that (using auto complete and adding the force-unwrapped optionals) but it still is producing the same errors. Other methods such as didPressAccessoryButton seem okay. Any other thoughts on why the superclass is not picking up the didPressSend method?